# Auto sort a sheet so that entries remain in their categories

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

So I want to sort my Spreadsheet on Google but it remain in the Categories that it's laid out. I can get to it sort double columns but the categories get messed up as they move away from where they should be. I'm constantly adding to this document and want the additions to auto sort into their needed locations.

**[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApnWR8uyyyeTdHZ2T1JRSjM2OHpobENtRktDR0RFa1E#gid=0)** the document, so you can get the idea of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The following script sorts parts of the active sheet by the first column. The parts are separated by blank entries in the first column. So, for example

```
+-------+
| Title |
+-------+
| sss   |
| bbb   |
|       |
| eee   |
| wwww  |
| ccc   |
+-------+
```

becomes

```
+-------+
| Title |
+-------+
| bbb   |
| sss   |
|       |
| ccc   |
| eee   |
| wwww  |
+-------+
```

See also the comments included in the code.

It only does the "sorting within each category" part, not "analyze input and move it to the correct category" part; I felt the latter was under-specified and would warrant a separate question.

```
function sortRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var width = range.getWidth();  
  var values = range.getValues();
  var j = 1;                       // assuming the header row; otherwise j=0
  var len = values.length;          
  for (var i = 1; i<len; i++) {    // assuming the header row; otherwise i=0
    if (!values[i][0]) {
      if (i>j+1) {
        range.offset(j, 0, i-j, width).sort(1);   // (1) is the column to sort by
      }
      j = i+1;
    }
  }
  if (j<len-1) {
    range.offset(j, 0, len-j, width).sort(1);     // (1) is the column to sort by
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the SORT function:

SORT(data, keyColumn_1, ascOrDesc_1, keyColumn_2, ascOrDesc_2, ..., keyColumn_30, ascOrDesc_30)

Returns the rows in the given data range (or array), sorted according to the given key columns.
There are two ways to specify the key column: either as a column within the data range, or as another column outside the range. To specify a column within the data range, give its index within the range: 1 is the first column of the range, 2 is the second column, etc. To specify another column outside the range (e.g. an intermediate calculated value that you don't want to include in your output), just specify it as a range.
Each key column must also be marked to sort either ascending or descending, by adding either TRUE or FALSE after that specifying that key column. You can also specify only a single array or range. In that case, the function returns that range sorted ascending by the columns from left to right.

In your case, it'd be something like =SORT(A2:E13,1,True).

Comment: Only problem with the Sort function, as I've tried this, is that the divided categories get scrambled into the mix.

My idea was something like this (pseudocode time)
On Edit
Move Entry to X category based on Y Values
Sort X Category by First letter